# Errors in appcompat v7r21 file in eclipse android sdk.

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-appcompat

The errors in appcompat file isn't getting sorted out by any manner.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.    themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v14    line 29 Android AAPT Problem

Errors like above are shown in console window.

Answer (score 0):

Look at *Properties/Android/Project Build Target* of library project appcompat: Android 5.0 needs to be checked.